# debian : disable discrete gpu

Tags: debian, nvidia, gpu, radeon

I searched and only found an article written by 2012 which is too old.

I have HD 5450 and GT610 and Ryzen 5700G on msi b550 (I study KVM),and I want to disable HD 5450 and GT610 on normal time.

Is there any solution or another plan such as switch ,except BIOS modify?

Comment: Why is it too old?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is written on 2012 year ,so I wonder if it is changed on situation,and it is not new-bie friendly